# Using jQuery to perform a function IF a select menu has no select attribute

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

So, I'm dealing with a couple different plugins and I need to be able to perform a function if a select menu has no attribute.  I've been stumped on this and looked up many different methods with no success so far.

I have a select structured like so:

```
<div class="quantity_select">
<select name="cart[d3207bfbf377b2c6a2d5f0f397ecef61][qty]" title="Qty" class="qty">
        <option value="500" data-qty="500" data-price="0.27" selected="">
            500&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$135.00            </option>
        <option value="1000" data-qty="1000" data-price="0.18">
            1000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$180.00            </option>
        <option value="2000" data-qty="2000" data-price="0.15">
            2000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$300.00            </option>
        <option value="5000" data-qty="5000" data-price="0.15">
            5000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$750.00            </option>
</select>
</div>
```

And I need to be able to validate that this is or isn't selected and either perform a function or not based on the result.  So this is the script I'm working with:

```
$('.qty').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ( !$('option:selected',this).index() <= 0) {
            $('.actions').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
        }
});
```

There will be more than one select with the same class `qty` so it needs to loop through and check each one.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Is it the `'option:selected',this`? I would imagine this works.  The console isn't throwing any errors either so is it that I'm not actually validating if it's checked?

I have two selects on my test page one with `selected=""` and one without so it should trigger.

Comment: ``if ( $(this).find('option:selected').length <= 0) ) {...}``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
$('.qty').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ( $('option:selected',this).length > 0) {
            $('.actions').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
        }
});
```

$('option:selected',this) returns an array of selected options so checking the array's index probably won't work.

Comment: Your option will trigger but it begins a loop because updating the cart reloads the page.  I only want it to do this if the selected attribute exists at all. I think the issue is that there is no length for the attribute because it is checking `selected=""` and seeing no length.

Comment: This query doesn't return the length of the attribute, it returns the length of the array of options that are selected (for a dropdown this will be zero or one, for a multiselect list box it can be zero to many). You can check if the selected attribute exists another way is $("option[selected]").length. Again returning an array of options whree the selected attribute exists.

Comment: Perfect!  Your suggestion for using `$("option[selected]").length` was the ticket to solving the core problem I was having.  I've noticed though that when the script runs doesn't seem to loop correctly and only triggers if that's true for the first select.  Since they all have the same class `qty` you would think that `.each` would work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the function within the 'each' does it get hit multiple times? You said earlier that the click of the button refreshes the page, that could be preempting the loop from continuing.